# Can I send zip pairs to Google's Distance matrix API?

Tags: c#

I see that I can send in 'addresses' or lat/lons. I'm trying to determine if I can send in US zip codes. Will the API convert them to city/states on the back end? When I go to the standard, online Google Maps and ask for directions, it will allow me to type only zip codes, I want to know if the Distance Matrix API will return distances if I pass zip codes instead of addresses or lat/lons.
Thank you!

Comment: How accurate do you want the distances and from what locations?  Addresses or lat/long will be much more accurate then from city hall (when you use city or zip code).

Comment: Thanks for the response.I'm just trying to determine if the API will handle a zip pair, or if zips. If I just go to Google Maps and enter two zip codes and ask for directions, it comes back with the distance, and the city,state associated with the zip codes. I want to know if I can pass zip codes into the Distance Matrix API and expect the same distance back.